# How do I merge space-separated files of unequal length (inner join) using join in linux?

Tags: linux, join

I have a simple problem: I have a space separated file and want to add a column from another space separated file, but this second file is longer. I want to perform an inner join (so only add the column and not rows). I want to do it with linux join (for efficiency reasons). I have seen similar questions but as I'm only a beginner I can't distill the information I need and apply it to my case.

I removed headers and sorted on the key column (first column in both files). I checked for duplicate keys (there were none).

```
join -1 1 -1 1 <(sort -k1 file1) <(sort -k1 file2) > file3

File 1:
rs1248851 C 655 0.7666 -0.8358 0.4033
rs1248857 G 654 1.069 0.4283 0.6684
rs1248860 G 656 1.052 0.3234 0.7464
rs12488651 G 652 1.246 1.343 0.1792
rs1248865 C 649 0.7419 -0.9125 0.3615
rs1248866 C 649 0.7696 -0.8053 0.4207
rs1248868 C 649 0.7717 -0.8317 0.4056
rs1248869 T 647 0.7878 -0.766 0.4437

File 2:
rs1248851 G
rs1248857 A
rs1248858 C
rs1248859 C
rs1248860 A
rs1248861 T
rs12488651 T
rs1248865 G
rs1248866 G
rs1248867 G
rs1248868 T
rs1248869 C

Expected result File 3:
rs1248851 C 655 0.7666 -0.8358 0.4033 G
rs1248857 G 654 1.069 0.4283 0.6684 A
rs1248860 G 656 1.052 0.3234 0.7464 A
rs12488651 G 652 1.246 1.343 0.1792 T
rs1248865 C 649 0.7419 -0.9125 0.3615 G
rs1248866 C 649 0.7696 -0.8053 0.4207 G
rs1248868 C 649 0.7717 -0.8317 0.4056 T
rs1248869 T 647 0.7878 -0.766 0.4437 C


Actual resulting error message:
join: /dev/fd/63:5: is not sorted: rs1248865 C 649 0.7419 -0.9125 0.3615
join: /dev/fd/62:8: is not sorted: rs1248865 G
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your logic with `join` or why it complains, but ...

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0};NR!=FNR{if($1 in a){print a[$1],$2}}' file1 file2
rs1248851 C 655 0.7666 -0.8358 0.4033 G
rs1248857 G 654 1.069 0.4283 0.6684 A
rs1248860 G 656 1.052 0.3234 0.7464 A
rs12488651 G 652 1.246 1.343 0.1792 T
rs1248865 C 649 0.7419 -0.9125 0.3615 G
rs1248866 C 649 0.7696 -0.8053 0.4207 G
rs1248868 C 649 0.7717 -0.8317 0.4056 T
rs1248869 T 647 0.7878 -0.766 0.4437 C
```

Let's break the awk down;  while `NR` (the record number in the input over all) matches `FNR` (file record number) we save each line into an array, using the first column's entries as an index.

When we reach the second file, and its first column can be found in our previously created array, we print the line from the first file followed by the second column from the second file.

Comment: I'm not sure how but your awk solution works fine, thanks!

Comment: I get some sense of what you mean but I'll need to familiarize myself more with the awk program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `join` command on linux seems more verbose, but still results in a `file3` file with the expected results. `join` on macOS does not complain.

If you still want to use something else, you could try filtering `file2` based on the keys present in `file1`, like this:

```
for i in `cut -f1 -d' ' file1`; do grep $i file2 >> file2.filtered; done;
```

And then use the original `join` you already had:

```
join -1 1 -1 1 <(sort -k1 file1) <(sort -k1 file2.filtered) > file3
```

Comment: Funny that it works without issues on mac. Anyway your solution works for me as well, thank you!